# Migrate multiple branches from Perforce to Git

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to migrate perforce repository to Git using git-p4 tool, but struggling with branch configuration. Consider the following P4 layout:

```
Folder1/
-- SubFolder1/
-- SubFolder2/
Folder2/
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Here, I need to migrate SubFolder1 and SubFolder2 as a separate branches, while keeping Folder2, file1 & file2 in master branch.

I tried specifying the following config in p4.branchList config:

```
git config --add git-p4.branchList DEPOT_PATH/Folder1/SubFolder1:Branch1
git config --add git-p4.branchList DEPOT_PATH/Folder1/SubFolder2:Branch2
git config --add git-p4.branchList DEPOT_PATH/Folder1:master
```

but I got this error which is not very helpful:

```
p4 describe -s 521710 did not return 1 result: [{'generic': 33, 'code': 'error', 'data': "Operation 'user-describe' failed.\nChange 521705 description missing!\n", 'severity': 4}, {'p4ExitCode': 1}]
```

Pretty sure I'm doing something incorrectly, I'm not even sure if the current layout migration is possible with git-p4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE

I forgot to mention that I tried running p4 describe command as indicated in error message, but I got another error stating that "change description is missing".

Comment: Can you try `p4 describe 521705`

Comment: Hi Douglas, thanks for the reply. I updated the post

Comment: Sounds like you've got some corruption in your perforce repository - you shouldn't have missing descriptions for changesets that exist in the history.

Comment: I ignored that part of the issue. Fixing the branch configuration will not help you overcome this type of errors.

Comment: BTW, you can use `p4 change -u` to update the change description if you're its owner.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not completely sure it is possible to do what you want.
The branch detection was implemented assuming that each branch resided in a complete independent directory structure, and not under sub-directories.

Nonetheless, you should not be using the depot path in that configuration. Those are directory pairs that are always related with the original depot path used during the import process. Please note that each pair should be the source and destination directories of an `integrate` (or similar) operation. That is, assume you have the following structure:

```
//depot/project/main
//depot/project/branch1
//depot/project/branch2
```

And that the branches were created using:

```
p4 integrate //depot/project/main //depot/project/branch1
p4 integrate //depot/project/branch1 //depot/project/branch2
```

Then you need to configure the following branches when importing using `git p4 clone //depot/project/...@all`:

```
git config --add git-p4.branchList main:branch1
git config --add git-p4.branchList branch1:branch2
```

---

So, following your specific example, if you imported using the following command:

```
git p4 clone --detect-branches //depot/path/...@all
```

Then you only need to include the path *after* the `/path/` part.

Assuming the DEPOT_PATH `//depot/project_root` and the import command `git p4 clone --detect-branches //depot/...@all`, you would need the following configurations:

```
git config --add git-p4.branchList project_root:project_root/Folder1/SubFolder1
git config --add git-p4.branchList project_root:project_root/Folder1/SubFolder2
```

That is, both SubFolder1 and SubFolder2 were integrated from project_root.

Comment: Hi @Vitor, thanks for the reply. I'm a bit confused, as doesn't source:destination pair represent P4 folder to git branch map? If so, why did you mention P4 path in git branch name..? if not what am I missing? :) Anyway, going to try this now. thanks again :)

Comment: They are source:destination pairs inside P4 depot, in the sense that if you `p4 integrate //depot/project/path1 //depot/project/path2` you can clone it with `git p4 clone //depot/project/...@all` and tell git-p4 that path2 is a branch of path1.

Comment: I see now. I thought the mapping represented P4 branch path to git branch name. So does this mean that I should map all source->destination branches? I tried migrating several other projects to git, and for all of them, I get an error saying:

fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/p4/dvt_bsg/rel/R2.4.2.78': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. I saw your other answer that this error is related to branch mapping issue and I guess I should provide a proper mapping, but I didn't get how to determine whats the proper mapping are...

Comment: As far as I can tell, you did not describe this specific error in the original question. You might want to report this error to the git mailing list, along with your git-p4 configurations and a complete log of the import process using --verbose. Careful not to share sensitive information.